# A problem on spectrum of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, functional-calculus

Let $A$ be a positive self-adjoint linear operator (not necessarily bounded) in the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Then $a=(1+A)^{-1}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. For a given $n$, let us consider the projection $e_n:={\chi}_n(a)$ in $\mathcal{R}(\{a\})$ ($\mathcal{R}(\{a\})$ stands for the von Neumann algebra generated by the element $a$). Then both of $Ae_n$ and $ae_n$ are bounded self-adjoint operators in $\mathcal{R}(\{a\})$.

**Problem:** Prove that for $\lambda\neq0$, $\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}\in\sigma(Ae_n)\implies\lambda\in\sigma(ae_n)$.

**P.S.** I got stuck in this while reading [Section $9.10$](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YoUaXU8j_oUG-U8CuGrwuo3JapVFPpIm/view?usp=sharing) of the book 'Lectures on von Neumann algebras' by Strătilă and Zsidó. More specifically, where they consider the map $\mathcal{B}(\sigma(Ae_n))\ni f\mapsto F_f(ae_n)\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. To make sense of this, we need to have $F_f$ defined on $\sigma(ae_n)$ for $f$ defined on $\sigma(Ae_n)$. But $F_f(\lambda):=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if } \lambda=0,\\
f((1-\lambda)/\lambda) &\text{ if } \lambda\in (0,1]. 
\end{cases}$.
Hence I got the above problem. I was trying with the property that $\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}\in\sigma(Ae_n)\implies f((1-\lambda)/\lambda)\in\sigma(f(Ae_n))$ for any continuous function $f$ on $\sigma(Ae_n)$ but did not get anything. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
e_n=1_{\big(\tfrac1{n+1},\infty\big)}(a)=1_{\big(\tfrac1{n+1},\infty\big)}((1+A)^{-1})=1_{(0,n)}(A). 
$$
Then
$$
Ae_n=A\,1_{(0,n)}(A),$$
$$ae_n=(1+A)^{-1}\,1_{(0,n)}(A)=\Big(\tfrac1{1+t}\,1_{(0,n)}(t)\Big)(A).
$$
So, if $\lambda\in\sigma(ae_n)$, then $\lambda=\tfrac1{1+\alpha}$ with $\alpha\in\sigma(A)\cap(0,n)$ and
$$
\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}=\frac{1}{\lambda}-1=1+\alpha-1=\alpha.
$$
Conversely, if $\tfrac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}\in\sigma(Ae_n)$, then
$$
\lambda=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}}\in\sigma(ae_n). 
$$